# Convert `import ...` into `from ... import ...` in source code

Tags: python

I have a string in Python representing some code, and I want to replace the import statement for time with the corresponding from time import sleep if the code contains a method call like time.sleep(). Additionally, I want to replace the method call time.sleep() with sleep().

Here's an example of the code:

```
a = """
import math, numpy, random
import time
from PIL import Image
a = math.sin(90)
time.sleep(3)
"""
```

I would like to transform this code to:

```
a = """
import numpy, random
from math import sin
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image
a = sin(90)
sleep(3)
"""
```

I've tried using regular expressions, but I'm having trouble achieving the desired result. Can someone help me with the correct regular expression and replacement logic for this task?

Here is my code I tried:

```
re.sub(rf'import\s+{re.escape("time")}\s*\n*(\s*{re.escape("time")}\.(\w+)\(([^)]*)\))', lambda m: f'from {m.group(2)} import {m.group(3)}, {m.group(2)}' if 'time' in m.group(2) else f'from {m.group(2)} import {m.group(3)}', a)
```

Comment: Pycharm will do this automatically for you with right click refactor. I believe there is a free community edition as well

Answer (score 9):

To transform `import module` into a `from module import names, ...` statement you should first collect those `names`, i.e. attribute accesses in the code. Parse the code into AST, find the `ast.Attribute` nodes, and store the name-to-attributes mapping in a dict of sets:

```
import ast

tree = ast.parse(code)
attr_usage = {}
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
        attr_usage.setdefault(node.value.id, set()).add(node.attr)
```

You can then use a [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) subclass to replace `Import` nodes with `ImportFrom` nodes with names in the corresponding sets, and replace `Attribute` nodes whose names are of those modules in the dict with corresponding `Name` nodes. In case there are unused modules in the code that should remain with an `import` statement, you can use a separate list comprehension to filter names in the attribute mapping from the list of import names:

```
class IndividualizeImportNames(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, attr_usage):
        self.attr_usage = attr_usage

    def visit_Import(self, node):
        leftover_imports = []
        if unused_names := [
            alias for alias in node.names
            if alias.name not in self.attr_usage
        ]:
            leftover_imports.append(ast.Import(names=unused_names))
        return leftover_imports + [
            ast.ImportFrom(
                module=alias.name,
                names=[
                    ast.alias(name=attr) 
                    for attr in self.attr_usage[alias.name]
                ]
            )
            for alias in node.names if alias.name in self.attr_usage
        ]

    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if node.value.id in self.attr_usage:
            return ast.Name(id=node.attr, ctx=ast.Load())
        return node

IndividualizeImportNames(attr_usage).visit(tree)
```

Combine the two steps above into a function:

```
def individualize_import_names(code):
    tree = ast.parse(code)
    attr_usage = {}
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
            attr_usage.setdefault(node.value.id, set()).add(node.attr)
    IndividualizeImportNames(attr_usage).visit(tree)
    return ast.unparse(tree)
```

so that:

```
original_code = """
import math, numpy, random
import time
from PIL import Image
a = math.sin(90)
time.sleep(3)
"""
print(individualize_import_names(original_code))
```

outputs:

```
import numpy, random
from math import sin
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image
a = sin(90)
sleep(3)
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVQ9j9QwEK1o_CusrRwRIiQaOCkFDdJKpxMF3WoVmfVkzyJxIn8sHIiOf0FzDfwofg3jcTZfu3eudjNv3sx7Y8_vv_2Dv-_M4-Of4OtXb_-9-KXbvrOeS-cZOzTSOb41Sp-0CrLR32FL4TvZghOIKe46BZ-sNK7ubAs2u2Ecj4KaV5U22leVcNDUOZfe2yo4eYQBE08MFVOElzMYG5lO2iFRqjywGSw742mg9t0JbJW6d0i0249RXfNgggNVmdg3v8HoGIwHlUnHUcHwSxsqUBB8gUQqglAIQT5iVyrGhP3NInfdZCH7HowiGwdxVLCcN5tlI4cFH6y51PpyrWbk-2C7Vixi8bSdCg2Uk478ApL62F18P9NTLnVbRt0Zv4okQzF8xaPdVH1_kbv8ki3-PTGk1WCeG8r6Xr1HjP4cPFy_WsRzBANWHyrKEISY3y7q4ySbAIVWV4ov78EwR3o92KzQqiSCiM_5wX8rY-i2k0pcTj8iGYvd6_mzHC5DujPiMEnwFuhZIWMvrYMUo9Di3f34yc72xhJRRMz5KpsvInLMHEHBaINxXpoDkBk5YUcjs6XeqU7hwGPrMjTJxNGzHB3zqLaQSonRjNTm0-tn2ihFGgw1ylYeB5OEpyDrrD5qI5sqGoHCN5sNG3ZeK_09zj-0_UPOcaeprj2HvG6B1fic-MftLR8-btt4sSSSxMwCPRHvXmcsYgvXAPTiTcYif2-18eKZgS2ayrK0jIedfN7N_wE)

Comment: It is far more robust and general to parse the program as shown in this answer than to fiddle around with regexes (which cannot describe Python's grammar anyways)!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def transform_code(code:str)->str:
    lines=code.split('\n')

    libs=set() #Find all imported libraries
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('import '):
            new_libs=re.findall(r"[\s,^]*(\w+)[\s,]*",line[7:])
            libs.update(new_libs)
    lines=list(filter(lambda x:not x.startswith('import '),lines))

    requires={k:set() for k in libs} #Find out how the library is being used
    for index,line in enumerate(lines):
        new_requires=re.findall(r"(\w+)\.(\w+)",line)
        for lib,mothod in new_requires:
            if lib in libs:
                lines[index]=line.replace(lib+".","")
                requires[lib].add(mothod)

    for lib,methods in requires.items(): #Generate Import Code
        if methods:
            lines.insert(0,f"from {lib} import {', '.join(methods)}")

    unused_libs=[k for k,v in requires.items() if not v] #Generate Unused Import Code
    if unused_libs:
        lines.insert(0,f"import {', '.join(unused_libs)}")
    return '\n'.join(lines)

a="""import math,numpy,random
import time
from PIL import Image
a = math.sin(90)
time.sleep(3)
"""
print(transform_code(a))
```

This will output

```
import random, numpy
from math import sin
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image
a = sin(90)
sleep(3)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

def transform_code(code):
    if 'time.sleep(' in code:
        code = re.sub(r'import time\n', 'from time import sleep\n', code)
        code = re.sub(r'time\.sleep\(', 'sleep(', code)

    # Replace other import statements (e.g., 'import math' -> 'from math import sin')
    def replace_imports(m):
        module = m.group(1)
        functions = set(re.findall(r'\b' + re.escape(module) + r'\.(\w+)', code))
        return 'from {} import {}\n'.format(module, ', '.join(functions)) if functions else ''

    code = re.sub(r'import (\w+)', replace_imports, code)
    return code

a = """import math, numpy, random
import time
from PIL import Image
a = math.sin(90)
time.sleep(3)"""

transformed_code = transform_code(a)
print(transformed_code)
```

Comment: Thank you but the output was `from math import sin
, numpy, random     
from time 
from PIL 
a = math.sin(90)    
sleep(3)` which is not what i expected.

Comment: def transform_code(code):
    if 'time.sleep(' in code:
        code = re.sub(r'time\.sleep\(', 'sleep(', code)
        code = re.sub(r'\bimport time\b', 'from time import sleep', code)

    # This is a simplified approach and may not handle all cases.
    def replace_math_import(m):
        functions = set(re.findall(r'\bmath\.(\w+)', code))
        return 'from math import ' + ', '.join(functions) if functions else m.group(0)

    code = re.sub(r'import math', replace_math_import, code)
    return code

Answer (score -2):

```py
from string import *

def myFunc(code:str):
    """The main function that will change the code"""

    code2 = "" # the output string
    funcs = {} # the dict which will map modules to their functions

    #################### parsing
    for line in code.split('\n'):
        words = line.split(' ')
        if words[0] == 'from': # from `words[1]` import `funcs...`
            funcs = add_func(words[1], find_items(line), funcs)
        else:
            for word in words:
                if '.' in word:
                    funcs = add_func(word[:word.find('.')], [word[word.find('.')+1 :word.find('(')]], funcs)
    ############################
                    
    ############ creating output
    for line in code.split('\n'):
        words = line.split(' ')
        words = [word.replace(',', '') for word in words] # delete commas
        if words[0] == 'import': # if the line starts with `import`
            mods = [mod for mod in find_items(line)] # find all modules that were imported in that line
            for mod in mods:
                if mod in funcs: # if their functions were used in code
                    code2 += f"from {mod} import {', '.join(funcs[mod])}\n"
                    words.remove(mod)
            if (words[1:]): # if their functions weren't used (like `numpy` in this case)
                code2 = f"import {', '.join(words[1:])}\n" + code2

        elif words[0] == "from": # if the line starts with `from`
            new_line = f"from {words[1]} import {', '.join(funcs[words[1]])}"
            code2 += new_line + '\n'
        
        elif '.' in line: # if the a method runs in that line
            new_line = [c for c in line]
            # this loop deletes module name + '.' in that line e.g.  time.sleep(3) -> sleep(3)
            for i in range(line.find('.'), -1, -1):
                if line[i].lower() not in ascii_lowercase + '.':
                    break
                new_line.pop(i)
            code2 += ''.join(new_line) + '\n'
        
        else: # if a function runs in that line e.g. `print` in this case
            code2 += line + '\n'

    return code2
       

def add_func(module:str, new_funcs:list, funcs:dict) -> dict:
    """Used for adding a function to a module in `funcs` dict"""
    if module in funcs: # if the module has already some functions mapped to it
        funcs[module].extend(new_funcs)
    else:               # create a new list of functions for the module
        funcs[module] = new_funcs
    return funcs

def find_items(line:str) -> list:
    """returns a list of items:
    - functions that were imported in this format:\n
    from module import [func0, func1, func2, ...]
    
    - modules that were imported in this format:\n
    import [m0, m1, m2, ...]"""

    f_list = line[line.find('import') + 6:].strip().split(',')
    for i in range(len(f_list)):
        f_list[i] = f_list[i].strip()
    
    return list(set(f_list))

a = """
import math, numpy, random, pandas
import time
from PIL import Image
a = math.sin(90)
time.sleep(3)
print("hi")
"""

print(myFunc(a))
```

will output:

```
import numpy, random, pandas

from math import sin
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image
a = sin(90)
sleep(3)
print("hi")
```

- It will respect calls of built-in functions or functions that weren't imported
- It will put imported modules before imported functions
- It will remove "dot-notation"